# iphone network multithreading

Tags: iphone

I have a class for receiving data from network,named NetWorkConnect.the following method is in NetWorkConnect.m,this is delegate method. m_DisplayMarketViewController is an instance of class DisplayMarketViewController.

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream*)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode{
    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        {
            if (data == nil) {
            data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            }
            uint8_t buf[1024];
            unsigned int len = 0;
            len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buf maxLength:1024];
            if(len) {    
            [data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];
            } else {
            NSLog(@"No data.");
            }  
           [self storeData:data];              
           [m_DisplayMarketViewController updateMarket:self];                   
    } break;  
    default:
      break;
    }
}
```

the method updateMarket passes the self to DisplayMarketViewController,so DisplayMarketViewController can use the data which received from network.and in DisplayMarketViewController.m file the data will be displayed.but when I update the data,i can display the data ,but the  inteface seems a little blocked,so I intend to use multiThreading....but how to do it?thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can subclassing  NSOperation and in implementation file you can try something like this.

- (void)main 
{
    @try 
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        executing_ = YES;
       [self performSelector:@selector(makeSomethingInBackground:) onThread:[NSThread      currentThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[pool drain];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e)  {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Overrides

- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isExecuting
{
    return executing_;
}

- (BOOL)isFinished
{
    return finished_;
}

- (void)cancel
{
    [super cancel];
    [self done];
}
In another class create instance of your NSOperation subclass.
YourNSOperationSubclass *operation = [YourNSOperationSubclass new];
NSOperationQueue *op = [NSOperationQueue new];  [op addOperation operation];
```

Comment: firstly,thank you.'-(void)stream:(NSStream*)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode;'is a delegate method,so is it the same as your method "makeSomethingInBackground"?and this method will be called for each one second,is it also the same as your method?

Comment: makeSomethingInBackground  that method will run in separate thread , you can use  "updateMarket" instead of "makeSomethingInBackground"

Comment: take a look here is an example that may help you    http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/

Comment: also I found another one ...   http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/23/nsoperation-example/